# mockito + easymock - NoClassDefFoundError:net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer

Tags: java, junit, mockito, noclassdeffounderror, powermock

I am writing a test using easymock + powermock, the reason I am using powermock is to mock a static method.

my test class looks like:

```
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.mockStatic;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StaticTest.class)
public class DummyTest {
    @Test
    public void testDummy() {
        mockStatic(StaticTest.class);
        Mockito.when(StaticTest.testMethod()).thenReturn("hello world");
        ........
}
```

here is my test dependencies and versions:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Running the test, I got initializationError as below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer
at org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl.isProxy(ProxyFrameworkImpl.java:29)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getUnmockedType(WhiteboxImpl.java:1783)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getType(WhiteboxImpl.java:2237)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.setInternalState(WhiteboxImpl.java:327)
at org.powermock.reflect.proxyframework.RegisterProxyFramework.registerProxyFramework(RegisterProxyFramework.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:2014)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:885)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:859)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:466)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.registerProxyframework(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:154)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.getPowerMockTestListenersLoadedByASpecificClassLoader(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:144)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:143)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 39 more
```

has anybody run into this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) in your classpath.

Comment: I've heard that dependency issue is solved in higher version of easymock?

Comment: Nope, the latest [documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html) mentions that it is still dependent on cglib.

Comment: I have added cglib and i still have the exception. I have added the lib via gradle and as a module , and ether way the exception still comes up

Comment: I put that in my gradle build, but still get an error: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/cglib/proxy/Enhancer**

Answer (score 1):

Adding cglib dependency in maven solved me initializationError problem for powermock 1.5.5 as mentioned by @Premraj. For 1.4.12 Powermock probably version 2.2.2 of cglib should do it.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>cglib</groupId>
     <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
     <version>3.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding cglib dependency didn't work. I solved the problem using:

```
<!--
    We depend on the EasyMock API but exclude the EasyMock dependency. The reason
    is that PowerMock Whitebox needs a "org.powermock.reflect.spi.ProxyFramework"
    implementation in order to work correctly. This implementation is provided by
    the extension API:s. Since JMock uses CGLib it can reuse the
    "org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl" in the
    PowerMock EasyMock API. An alternative to depend on this class would be to simply copy
    the class it into your code (remember that the class must be named
    org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl).
-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

as presented [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/source/browse/trunk/examples/jmock/pom.xml). Note I'm not using easymock (I use mockito instead)

Comment: Easymock is not compatible with mockito.

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple  option, finally below dependency worked for me.
Should use the higher version of PowerMock and Mockito to work in spring boot application.

Below is the maven dependency:

spring-boot: 2.0.1.RELEASE( contains junit: 4.12  version by default)

`
        1.8
        2.0.0-beta.5

```
</properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>'
```

Comment: powermock-version: 1.8 2.0.0-beta.5

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue after adding below dependencies.

```
testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5')
testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-beta.5')
```