# Runtime error PowerMock + Mockito: ProxyFrameworkImpl could not be located in classpath

Tags: java, android, gradle, mockito, powermock

I am trying to use PowerMock with the Android InstrumentTestCase
Since my test runs on an Android device the libraries needs to be added to the apk.

I encounter big issues with powermock+mockito and Dex files.
I have a runtime error with only powermock+mockito in my dependencies:

```
org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl could not be located in classpath.
```

And a compilation error if I include either cglib/cglib-nodep (has suggested in [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223640/mockito-easymock-noclassdeffounderrornet-sf-cglib-proxy-enhancer)):

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lnet/sf/cglib/beans/BeanCopier$BeanCopierKey
```

Here is a part of my gradle.build:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'
androidTestCompile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:3.2.0'
androidTestCompile 'cglib:cglib:3.2.0'
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Not yet, I have postpone the issue.
I tried to downloads the libraries and If you take a look at the content you can see that they have both the same jar. It should be removed from one library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also tried to use PowerMock for Android instrumentation tests and got stuck with the same issue.

Here is what I've found on [PowerMock github](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/594#issuecomment-162784778)

> PowerMock won't work on Android if you run it on a device since PowerMock is using JVM byte code manipulation. It will work if you run it on a JVM though.

So, I guess PowerMock is only appropriate for unit testing on Android.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I have gave up because of a lack of information.

Comment: Sure! Actually, there should be some different approaches to insert mock stuff into the instrumentation tests. For example, one can be redesigned to Robolectric unit test and then we can use either PowerMock or Mockito. As I remember I solved my problem this way.